# Git rename directory with submodules

Tags: git

Given a git repository, with a directory in which I've checked out a submodule, how can I rename the top level directory?

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/work/asdasd/.git/
$ mkdir asd
$ touch asd/.keepme
$ git add asd/.keepme
$ git commit -a -m "asd"
[master (root-commit) 932f011] asd
  0 files changes
  create mode 100644 asd/.keep
$ git submodule add git@github.com:test/test.git asd/subdir
Cloning into 'asd/subdir'...
remote: Counting objects: 800, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (281/281), done.
remote: Total 800 (delta 523), reused 786 (delta 509)
Receiving objects: 100% (800/800), 109.46 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (523/523), done.
$ git commit -a -m "submodule"
[master e0fe8e7] submodule
  2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
  create mode 100644 .gitmodules
  create mode 160000 asd/subdir
```

Now, if i try to rename the `asd` directory, I'm getting an error:

```
 $ git mv asd foo
 fatal: source directory is empty, source=asd/subdir, destination=foo/subdir
```

How can I rename it?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `mv asd foo`, then `git add -u *` (u is for update) and then you commit and push the changes?

Comment: This doesn't work, ```git add -u``` doesn't report any error, however, it doesn't add ```foo``` either (it stays in an untracked state). If I use ```git add``` it loses submodule information (adds like regular content)